# JetBrains PHPStorm Line Over DocBlock

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

When using PHPStorm from JetBrains, when editing a file, if I create a file or class docblock, there is a light gray underline on the previous line (or an over-line on the current line, if you will).

If I put new lines before the docblock, the gray line will move with the docblock, so I believe it's related to the docblock.

I can't figure out how to turn this line off (see image, the red arrow is pointing at the line). I've dug around in the editor or in the color scheme preferences.

Can someone help? (yes, this is the most minor of annoyances)

[image: Picture of line I'm referring to]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For lines between methods/functions:** `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | General | Appearance --> Show method separators`

**For lines between classes:** it cannot be turned off.

The only option here is to use the same color as background: `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General --> Method separator color`

---

**P.S.**
The path in settings is for PhpStorm v8.0.**2**. For 8.0.1 and older versions it will be slightly different.

You can always use **search box** in Settings (top left corner) or `Help | Find Action` or `Search Everywhere` functionality to find them (search for `method` or `separator` -- there will be not so many matches to check)

Comment: Thank you, LazyOne! That fixed it. You're apparently less lazy than me :-)